# Grid loses size when chaning DependencyProperty

Tags: c#, wpf, dependency-properties

I have 2 Controls in WPF. A "main control" and a "chart control", which draws a barchart based on on DataSet.

my main control initializes the chart control and binds the DatSet necessary for the drawing to its DependencyProperty. Since the DataSet i use has quite a few Tables, while I only need a single one for my chart, i recently created a new DataTable Property and forward the right Table from my DataSet to it.

```
 <Grid>

            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="3"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="3"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
<Grid Grid.Row="2" Background="#f0f0f0">
                <c:ChartControl  TableData="{Binding ChartTable, Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Height="Auto" Width="Auto" />
            </Grid>
[...]
</Grid>
```

I also changed my DependencyProperty in my ChartControl from DataSet to DataTable. Once my onDataPropertyChanged event fires, a method with following code will be called at the end:

```
if (TableData_ != null)
        {
            // previously DataTable ChartTable = dsData_.Tables[ChartTable].Copy();

            Grid gdChart = new Grid(); 
            gdChart.Width = MainGrid.ActualWidth;
            gdChart.Height = MainGrid.ActualHeight;
            foreach (DataRow row in TableData_.Rows)
            {
               // draw Chart
            }
MainGrid.Child = gdChart;
}
```

That's all I changed. It worked previously, the DependencyProperty has the right value, but for reasons beyond my knowledge, **the size of my MainGrid is always 0 now**. I didn't change or move a single line in my code, but to change the Properties in both controls from DataSet to DataTable and delete the Table i previously copied in my ChartControl. How does another DependencyProperty affect the size?

My ChartControl looks like this

```
<UserControl [...]>
     d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300" >
    <Viewbox x:Name="MainGrid" Height="Auto" Width="Auto" />
</UserControl>
```

Comment: As a note, setting `Mode=TwoWay` and `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` on the TableData Binding seems to be pointless.

Comment: I have another issue with some DependencyProperties not being updated despite the Property they depend on calls the PropertyChanged event as intended. I was just trying different things in order to find a solution.   Thanks for the hint tho.

Comment: Just in case it isn't clear, `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` has absolutely nothing to do with the `PropertyChanged` event of the INotifyPropertyChanged interface.

Comment: I'd bet `MainWindow.ActualWidth` is based on its content's width, thus on `gdChart.Width`; so when you set the later with the former, they're both 0. Can you try, to be sure, with `MainWindow.Width`?

Comment: The whole ChartControl is part of another control, which just forwards the size of the grid containing the ChartControl to the MainGrid. That's about 1300 px when using a DataSet as DependencyObject and 0 when using a DataTable, without changing anything else. The MainGrid is btw a ViewBox at the moment, because i still have some resizing issues with a regular grid. Will add some more Information in my Question.